# How to verify a person age/ID using third Party Software?

Tags: payment-processing

I've seen third party software/companies that verify a user's ID, the one I saw you simply held your drivers license, passport etc... up to the web cam and it would verify your ID. I don't want to process this info on my end. Does anyone know a company like this?

Answer (score -1):

There are quite a few companies who provide verification services. Most of them are country specific so if you need to check data across the globe then you most likely need to use several services. Take a look at

http://www.experian.com/ or http://www.veda.co.nz/home/identity-plus-product-information.dot

Be prepared these services are not free.